# Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '8.3.0', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources

Tags: java, android, build.gradle

i am using a bottom navigation third party library that not identified and throw this error Cannot resolve class com.aurelhubert.ahbottomnavigation.AHBottomNavigation and i am using this dependency implementation 'com.aurelhubert:ahbottomnavigation:2.3.4' and when finding the solution using ai the gemini was gived this solution Locate the Gradle cache directory:

Windows: C:\\Users\<username\>.gradle\\caches

Delete the entire caches directory. after deleting i am facing problem from this file and

`build.gradle.kts

buildscript {

dependencies {

classpath(libs.google.services)

}

}

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

plugins {

alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication) apply false

}

`